# How to store refresh token in database

Tags: node.js, jwt, refresh-token

I am a beginner in jwt, I have read some article about refresh token, and I knew that it is important to store refresh token in database. What happens when users login to multiple devices or when they logout, is it necessary to revoke the refresh token?

I tried to create a table that contains 2 column (user_id, refresh_token)
So How to store refresh token in database when user log out, or when users login to many devices.

Answer (score 1):

The way i would do this is to add a couple more columns. Generally it is helpful to have a column called "revoked" or "active" as well as a "token family".

The purpose of the revoked column is to be able to force a user logout, meaning the next time the user goes to renew their access_token it will be rejected, effectively logging them out. This can also be used when the user logs out manually.

In many cases you want to renew the refresh_token as well when you get a new access token. This is usually done with "rolling tokens" meaning a new one will be issued with the access token and the previous will be deactivated. In this case it is useful to assign any new initial login with a family, and giving any derivative tokens the same family.

If you want to log out from this device only, you revoke all the tokens from the family, and if you want to log out from ALL devices, you revoke all tokens from the user ID.

That being said, if you're not very comfortable with security related code, I would recommend using a service from someone who knows their stuff such as e.g. Auth0 to deal with your authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how stringent you want a 'session' to be. Either the user can have multiple sessions, one session per device type, or just one session period.

When the user logs in correctly, respond with `accessToken` and `refreshToken`. The `accessToken` allows the user to interact with 'private' routes and the `refreshToken` allows the user to get a new `accessToken`.

An `accessToken` usually lasts for a short time, maybe a few hours. If you use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) this would be in the `exp` header. When the access token expires, your can automatically request a new one with the refresh token, which is valid for longer (you decide how long).

If the user logs out, you remove the refresh token, so the session doesn't exist anymore and the user must manually log in again.

Usually you would have just one session, and for that your table could be just `(user_id, refresh_token, expires_at)`. If you want one per type your could have `(user_id, refresh_token, device_type, expires_at)`.

You could have any number of sessions and just append to the table, but that is not recommended.

Comment: I wonder that How can I know what the device_type when user login to a new device?

Comment: Depending on your client code there are probably libraries available, for instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-detector-js for javascript

Comment: I want my users can login to many browsers in the same time, each browser will contain a refresh token, so how can i implement that, what is the unique value that help me know which browser are requesting a refresh key?

Comment: you probably don't need a browser key, just create multiple records for each user with different tokens. If you require a unique key, just generate one and store it in local/session storage alongside your other tokens

Comment: With your opinion, When user login many difference browsers that means there are many refresh_token of that user in database. And when that user logout, I have to disable the refresh_token that user are using in that session, but i don't know which refresh_token to be dissable because there are a lot of refresh_token the user give when login to many difference browsers